# Time condition in elocuent where

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I trying to select the objects called programations in a bd table where the atribute end_at Is greater or equal than to a variable called $rightnow, both variables are a date type whit year, month, day, hour, minute and second. The problem is that the query only filters the year, month and day fields. Do not use hour, minutes, or seconds to filter. How can I make the filter complete?
I'm using a elocuent query in a laravel project.

```
$rightNow = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('America/Santiago'));
$formatted_date = $rightNow->toDateTimeString();
$programations = Programation::where('end_at', '>=', $formatted_date)->orderBy('play_at', 'asc')->get();
```

The table is in a MySQL database.

[image]

Comment: Can you echo the formatted date?  Try `echo $formatted_date`.

Comment: $formatted_date: 2016-11-23 22:31:37

Comment: Can you show a reproducible sample which demonstrates the problem?  From what I can see, the `WHERE` clause should be working.

Comment: If you have defined play_at and end_at as dates on your model you do not need to format your string. Laravel will handle the dates as expected so you can simply match with $rightNow

Comment: @FrankProvost in that case i have the same problem